# Sorting tables based on two columns on multiple sheets with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like the macro to filter all the failed results from every table from every sheet (each sheet has 1 table) and to sort them in ascending order using the dates from column "I".

[Here's what the macro does right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXDtm.png)

and

[Here's what I would like the macro to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn1hu.png)

Can anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
Sub Formatting

Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each sht In Sheets

If sht.Name <> "Original" Then

sht.Range("J1").AutoFilter 10, "=FAIL"
sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=sht.Columns("I"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes



End If

Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you sort first, and then apply the filter? That way your filtered results will already be in the desired order. Also, you should be able to very simply record a Macro of you doing exactly what you want, and then the macro recorder will auto-generate the VBA code you want to execute.

Comment: But if I record myself doing that what I tried to describe, the vba code will reference a table and a sheet. Although, I would like to use this code to format all the sheets except the "original".

Comment: I don't think it's possible to sort only the the result. Sorting is always applied to all values, whether hidden by the filter or not. Your desired result shows the data sorted in descending order.

Comment: I'm sorry English is not my native language. I actually am trying to sort all the values. I would just like them to only include the failed ones and sort them by using dates from column "I".

Comment: If you record your actions, you will be able to adapt the generated code to your specific use case. And you should definitely sort first, then filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you want. Before trying it please review the two column addresses.

```
Sub Formatting()

    Dim Sht     As Worksheet
    Dim Tbl     As ListObject
    
    
    For Each Sht In Worksheets
        If Sht.Name <> "Original" Then
            Set Tbl = Sht.ListObjects(1)
            With Tbl.Sort.SortFields
                    .Clear
                    .Add Key:= Tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(3), _
                         SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                         Order:=xlDescending, _
                         DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            End With
            With Tbl.Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
            Tbl.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter 9, "=FAIL"
        End If
    Next Sht
End Sub
```

The code presumes that your tables start in column 1 (that is column A). `Tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(3)` specifies the 3rd column in the table. If your table starts at column A then column T would be 20 and the 3 in my code must be replaced with 20. Similarly, `Tbl.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter 9, "=FAIL"` speficies column I only if the table's first column is A.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this for too long... At some point, I was thinking about using the listobject, but I didn't really know how to and then I didn't really bother with it. Thank you!